# Улучшение структуры базы данных

Tags: база-данных, диаграммы, реляционная-модель

Занимаюсь учебный проектном и необходимо создать базу данных. В базах данных не силен, но смог составить диаграмму. Есть ли возможность как-то улучшить эту БД? [image: ER_Диаграмма]

Comment: Почему `user_info` сделано отдельной таблицей от `user`? Склад у вас один? Заказ разве не должен содержать в себе список заказанных товаров? У заказа ещё дата-время наверное должны быть.

Comment: У вас в `user_info` есть адрес, по которому проживает юзер. А ещё где-то (скорее всего в `order`) должен быть адрес, по которому доставляется заказ. Ведь юзер может заказать товар не себе, а в подарок другому человеку.

Comment: Рядом с паролем должна храниться "соль".

Answer (score 0):

Напишу только про структурные изменения.

1. Если у одного пользователя одна корзина, то таблица basket не нужна. basket_product можно привязывать сразу к user_id.
2. Судя по полям product, он представляет тип товара, а не экземпляр товара. Но тогда что это за таблица type?
3. У product и basket_product должна быть связь один ко многим, поскольку один тип товара может лежать в разных корзинах.
4. Видимо product_stock это запись о количестве продукта на складе. Тогда у product_stock и product должна быть связь один к одному. И что значит size отдельно от amount? Если size - это размер всего склада, то он должен лежать в отдельной таблице склада, а не в продукте (или вообще выкинуть).
5. order должен содержать список продуктов. То-есть нужна таблица order_product, такая же как basket_product, но с order_id вместо user_id. Другими словами, order_product должна иметь связь один ко многим с order.
6. В order, поле price - логически избыточно, поскольку цену можно вычислить из списка товаров.

Comment: На заказ могла быть скидка, так что не обязательно `price` совпадает с суммой цен товаров. Ну и каждый раз считать сумму заказа по всем товарам в готовом заказе - так себе идея. Цены могли поменяться, ну и не оптимально это, лишние выборки из БД.

Comment: @CrazyElf Согласен, что зависит от бизнес логики. По поводу оптимальности хранения суммы отдельно - это уже осознанная денормализация, со всеми прилагающимися сложностями. Да и чаще всего, суммарную цену показывают там же, где и список товаров.